# How do I track app usage time in android?

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I have been searched for a long times, but I cannot solve this.

I am developing app usage appplication, and I want to make user can restrict app usage time.

lets say user want to restrict Youtube app usage time for 10 min.

1.
How can I make notification or toaster when Youtube app usage reach 10 min since user click button?(I know event handling)

2. can I make observer even my app goes backgroud? or even after detroyed?

Base on my search  [registerAppUsageObserver](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.java) looks like what I want to, but I cannot use it since its @hide

```
 public void registerAppUsageObserver(int observerId, @NonNull String[] observedEntities,
                long timeLimit, @NonNull TimeUnit timeUnit, @NonNull PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

I can try to use it by reflection but I think its not recommended.

I got one more good source [link](https://github.com/elastic/AndroidSDKMirror-28/blob/master/com/android/server/usage/UserUsageStatsService.java) but I don't know how to use it.

please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of work in this area. I'd like to direct you to my smartCBT GitHub that reviews in a given period of time what a person has been using their apps for (https://github.com/kris-geyer/smartCBT; in particular, check out https://github.com/kris-geyer/smartCBT/blob/master/app/src/main/java/kg/own/smartcbt/ViewModel/RetrieveUsageRecords.java).

First off, I wouldn't trust the usage stats manager. It's been very unreliable in the past for me. I think what you want to assess usage is usage events (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event). These give you a much more fine-grained account of android app usage which seem much more accurate. You will need to get special permission for this. I've actually, empirically tested the accuracy before and it is very high.

For the overall structure of what your app needs I think you want a foreground service that runs in the background routinely logging what the person is using their phone for. This database is only updated when apps are changed, so handling this might be a little tricky but you'll manage.

When the app has identified that the allotted amount of usage time for a particular app is up, then it can direct the user back to your app by launching a new activity from the foreground service. I'm not sure if this is still possible, the android permissions seem to change so quickly. What would be really cool is if you can get the app to play videos of the user telling themselves that they've used their phone too much and be productive.

Best of luck. :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. let me try it out and I will reply result :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example code for your reference to calculate the Usage time of apps in Android. Usage time here means the time for which the package(app) was visible to the user on his screen.

```
Map<String , Long> usageTimeOfApps = new HashMap<>();
    List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);
    for (UsageStats usageStats : usageStatsList) {
        String packageName = usageStats.getPackageName();
        long timefr=usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground();
        usageTimeOfApps.put(packageName,timefr);
    }
```

The problem with using UsageStats is that it calculates wrong results as it includes the time in which the app was in the foreground and in the background. (overlapping times calculated twice).

Instead, we use UsageEvents which tracks the foreground and background activity event of an app and keeps calculating the timespan between these two events. Here is an example code. Let's say we are tracking time usage for today (since midnight) for some popular social media apps. usageTimeOfApps map will return the MAP of package names of apps mapped with their time in milliseconds.

```
    private Map<String , Long> calculateTodaysUsageTime( ) {
    Map<String , Long> usageTimeOfApps = new HashMap<>();// return variable containing the usage time of our interested apps
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.whatsapp",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.instagram.android",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.facebook.katana",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.twitter.android",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.snapchat.android",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.linkedin.android",0L);
    usageTimeOfApps.put("com.google.android.youtube",0L);

    Map<String , Long> prev = new HashMap<>();
    prev.put("com.whatsapp", -1L);
    prev.put("com.instagram.android",  -1L);
    prev.put("com.facebook.katana", -1L);
    prev.put("com.twitter.android",  -1L);
    prev.put("com.snapchat.android",  -1L);
    prev.put("com.linkedin.android",  -1L);
    prev.put("com.google.android.youtube",  -1L);

    UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(startTime, endTime);
    usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(startTime, endTime);
    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
        usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
        String currPackageName=event.getPackageName();
        if (usageTimeOfApps.containsKey(currPackageName)) {
            if (event.getEventType() == 1) {
                prev.put(currPackageName, event.getTimeStamp());
            } else if (event.getEventType() == 2 && prev.containsKey(currPackageName) && prev.get(currPackageName) != -1) {
                Long time = usageTimeOfApps.get(currPackageName) + (event.getTimeStamp() - prev.get(currPackageName));
                usageTimeOfApps.put(currPackageName, time);
            }
        }
    }

    return usageTimeOfApps;
}
```